# I created the openstack instances but i cant ping the instances ip from outside soo how to configure it

Tags: openstack-neutron

I created the openstack instances but i cant ping the instances ip from outside soo how to configure it

I created the openstack instances but i cant ping the instances ip from outside soo how to configure it and it gives request timed out